# how to pass a list of json trigger.new of Event from trigger to future apex class method

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger EventCallout on Event (before insert) {


String jsonevents=Json.serialize(Trigger.new[0]);
ClubSpeedup.thePosting(jsonevents);
```

Comment: In my question i used String ,but i want to use list to pass it to future apex method

Comment: Why not just pass the Ids?

Comment: How to pass id as a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not serialize records to pass them to future methods. The simpler way is to pass a collection of ids and re-query for them.

```
@future
public static void myMethod(Set<Id> eventIds)
{
    List<Event> events = [SELECT ... FROM Event WHERE Id IN :eventIds];
    // logic here
}
```

Then in your trigger, just call:

```
MyClass.myMethod(trigger.newMap.keySet());
```

Comment: actually i am doing integration so i want to insert event fields to clubspeed,and clubspeed has different event fields so i have to change fields from clubspeed to salesforce Event so i required serialized json of event